# Handling RuntimeException errors in a BigQuery pipeline

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

When we use a BigQueryIO transform to insert rows, we have an option called:

`.withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)`

which instructs the pipeline to NOT attempt to create the table if the table doesn't already exist.  In my scenario, I want to trap all errors.  I attempted to use the following:

```
var write=mypipline.apply("Write table", BigQueryIO
    .<Employee>write()
    .to(targetTableName_notpresent)
    .withExtendedErrorInfo()
    .withFormatFunction(new EmployeeToTableRow())
    .withSchema(schema)
    .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
    .withTableDescription("My Test Table")
    .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
    .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
    .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

which tried to insert rows into a non-existent table.  What I found was a RuntimeException.  Where I am stuck is that I don't know how to handle RuntimeException problems.  I don't believe there is anything here I can surround with a try/catch.

This question is similar to this one:

[Is it possible to catch a missing dataset java.lang.RuntimeException in a Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline that writes from Pub/Sub to BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516657/is-it-possible-to-catch-a-missing-dataset-java-lang-runtimeexception-in-a-google)

but I don't think that got a working answer and was focused on a missing Dataset and not a table.

My exception from the fragment above is:

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/XXXX/datasets/jupyter/tables/not_here/insertAll?prettyPrint=false
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not found: Table XXXX:jupyter.not_here",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not found: Table XXXX:jupyter.not_here",
  "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:373)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:341)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:323)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:309)
    at .(#126:1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a `try/catch` directly from the `BigQueryIO` in the `Beam` job, if the destination table doesn't exist.

I think it's better to delegate this responsability outside of `Beam` or launch the job only if your table exists.

Usually a tool like `Terraform` has the responsability to create infrastructure, before to deploy resources and run `Beam` jobs.

If it's mandatory for you to check the existence of the table, you can create :

- A `Shell` script with `bq` and `gcloud` cli to check the existence before to launch the job
- A `Python` script to check the existence before to launch the job

**Python script :**

For `Python` there is the `BigQuery` `Python` [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-exists#bigquery_table_exists-python) :

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound

client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to determine existence.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table"

try:
    client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print("Table {} already exists.".format(table_id))
except NotFound:
    print("Table {} is not found.".format(table_id))
```

**BQ Shell script :**

```bash
bq show <project_id>:<dataset_id>.<table_id>
```

If the table doesn't exist, catch the error and do not start the `Dataflow` job.